# Generated Algebra Closed under Conjugation

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $\mathscr B$ be a set of continuous, complex-valued functions over some topological space $X$. Let $\mathscr G$ be the algebra generated by $\mathscr B$, *i.e.*, the smallest algebra containing $\mathscr B$.

Suppose that the collection of functions $\mathscr B$ is closed under conjugation. That is, if $f\in\mathscr B$, then $\overline f\in\mathscr B$. I want to show that $\mathscr G$, the generated algebra, is also closed under conjugations. I would appreciate any hints showing along what lines I should proceed.

(An **algebra** $\mathscr A$ of complex-valued continuous functions has the property that (i) $f,g\in\mathscr A$ implies $f+g\in\mathscr A$; (ii) $f\in\mathscr A$ and $z\in\mathbb C$ imply $z f\in\mathscr A$; and (iii) $f,g\in\mathscr A$ implies that $f\cdot g\in\mathscr A$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an algebra $\mathscr{A}$ of functions, let $\overline{\mathscr{A}}$ denote the set $\{\overline{f} : f \in \mathscr{A}\}$. Then $\overline{\mathscr{A}}$ is also an algebra, and $\mathscr{A}\cap \overline{\mathscr{A}}$ is an algebra of functions that is closed under conjugation. (You may need to prove these facts.)

Consider $\mathscr{G}\cap \overline{\mathscr{G}}$ in your situation. It is an algebra of functions containing $\mathscr{B}$, hence ...

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thank you very much!